# Difference in python between basestring and types.StringType?

Tags: python

What's the difference between:

```
isinstance(foo, types.StringType)
```

and

```
isinstance(foo, basestring)
```

?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For Python2: `basestring` is the base class for both `str` and `unicode`, while `types.StringType` *is* `str`. If you want to check if something is a string, use `basestring`. If you want to check if something is a bytestring, use `str` and forget about `types`.

Answer (score 11):

This stuff is completely different in Python3

`types` not longer has `StringType`
`str` is always unicode
`basestring` no longer exists

So try not to sprinkle that stuff through your code too much if you might ever need to port it

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(u'ciao', types.StringType)
False
>>> isinstance(u'ciao', basestring)
True
>>>
```

Pretty important difference, it seems to me;-).

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.x:

```
try:
    basestring        # added in Python 2.3
except NameError:
    basestring = (str, unicode)
...
if isinstance(foo, basestring):
    ...
```

Of course this might not work for Python 3, but I'm quite sure the 2to3 converter will take care of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3 you can use install `future` via `pip install future` and import `from past.builtins import basestring`.

```
from past.builtins import basestring
```

See https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#strings-and-bytes