# Recognizing value as a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, ascii, xlrd

This code is supposed to get a string value from a an excel file. The value is how ever not being recognized as a string. How can I get query as a string? str(string) doesn't seem to work.

```
def main():
    file_location = "/Users/ronald/Desktop/Twitter/TwitterData.xlsx" 
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location) #open work book
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
    num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
    curr_row = 0
    curr_cell = 3
    count = 0
    string = 'tweet'
    tweets = []
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1
        tweet = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
        tweet.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        #print tweet
        query = str(tweet)
        if (isinstance(query, str)):
            print "it is a string"
        else:
            print "it is not a string"
```

This is the error i keep getting.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   102-104: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Is your above code printing 'it is not a string' ? Highly unlikely.

Comment: Yep. It was, until I added this 'query = str(tweet)' and then I got the error above. @AnandSKumar

Comment: Why do you want to encode using `ascii` ?

Comment: i googled the problem, and a solution I found was to try it that way. It didn't work. All I am trying to do is trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: Don't do that, instead try `print(type(tweet))` and `print(repr(tweet))` . And check what its type is.

Comment: This is the output.  `<type 'unicode'>
u"I'll take Taylor Swift serious when she grows those horrible bangs out #terrible #youlook12 #Grammys #opener"`

Comment: Why are you using `str` instead of `unicode`, and why are you checking `isinstance` against `str` instead of `basestring`?

Comment: `<type 'unicode'>` -- so it's a string... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist i am still new to python. I didn't i could do that. I am still learning as I go along.  Thanks.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist  I am trying to get the tweet(which is supposed to be a string) and then pass it as a parameter to a function. But the function wasn't seeing the tweet as a string. That's my main issue. This is to check if the tweet was actually a string.

Comment: @user3078335 Read the question I linked. There are two distinct types in Python (`str` and `unicode` in Python 2, and `bytes` and `str` in Python 3) that are both string types. The tweet is unicode (which you almost certainly want) and is therefore a string. Your test is invalid because it only tests for one type.

Comment: Thanks!! I figured it out. Post the last comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinct types in Python that both represent strings in different ways.

1. `str` or `bytes`: This is the default in Python 2 (hence `str`), called `bytes` in Python 3. It represents a string as a series of bytes, which doesn't work very well for unicode, because each character is not necessarily one byte as in ASCII and some other encodings.
2. `unicode` or `str`: This is the default in Python 3. Unicode handles characters with accents and international characters, so especially when dealing with something like Twitter, that's what you want. In Python 2, this is also what causes some strings to have the little `u''` prefix.

Your "is this a string?" test consists of `isinstance(s, str)`, which only tests for the first type and ignores the other. Instead, you can test against [`basestring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633082/difference-in-python-between-basestring-and-types-stringtype) -- `isinstance(s, basestring)` -- as it is the parent of both `str` and `unicode`. This properly answers the question of "is this a string?" for Python 2, and it is why you were getting misleading results.

Note that if you ever migrate to Python 3, `basestring` does not exist. This is a Python 2 test only.